# What is Mycroft saying on his phone before he tells Sherlock not to interfere with Adler?

Tags: dialogue, sherlock

In *A Scandal in Belgravia*, Sherlock cracks the code and John confirms it's flight 007. This triggers Sherlock's recollection of Mycroft saying something earlier in the episode on his phone, "bond..."? I understand how 007 is "Bond" but Mycroft says a few words after "Bond" which leads Sherlock to hypothesize about Coventry. What are those words? And what do they mean?

Answer (score 7):

*Mycroft* just says *"Bond Air is go,"* meaning that this flight with number 007 (or the whole secret operation with this flight full of already dead supposed terrorism victims) has permission to proceed/start. It isn't just that dialogue from *Mycroft* that leads *Sherlock* to realize the true nature of the situation, but the whole context of events.

Answer (score 2):

Mycroft says," Bond Air is "Go"."